# Merge Two Sorted Lists - how 2 nodes can be linked

Tags: java

I want to ask a question about this merge 2 sorted linked lists exercise:

> Merge two sorted linked lists and return it as a sorted list. The list
> should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two lists.

```
Input: l1 = [1,2,4], l2 = [1,3,4]
Output: [1,1,2,3,4,4]

public class ListNode {
    int val; // value of the node = val 
    ListNode next; // this is the pointer to the next node, which is connected to this current node
    ListNode() {}
    ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
    ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
}
```

Here is my code

```
//21. Merge Two Sorted Lists
public class merge2linkedlists {

        public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2){
            ListNode output = new ListNode(0); //head 0 - will remove later         
            ListNode currentEnd = new ListNode(0); //the current end node
            output.next = currentEnd; // link head to the current end node
            
            
            while(l1 != null && l2 != null) {
                if(l1.val <= l2.val) {
                    currentEnd.next = l1; // link to the next node
                    l1 = l1.next; // move to the next node
                }
                else {
                    currentEnd.next = l2;
                    l2 = l2.next;
                }
                currentEnd = currentEnd.next; // change current end node
            }//end while
            
            if(l1 == null) {
                currentEnd.next = l2;
            }
            else {
                currentEnd.next = l1;
            }
            return output.next.next;
        }  


    //main function here
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new merge2linkedlists();
    }

    public merge2linkedlists() {
        ListNode l1 = new ListNode(10); // head
        l1.next = new ListNode(80); 
        l1.next.next = new ListNode(150);
        l1.next.next.next = new ListNode(250);

        ListNode l2 = new ListNode(60); // head
        l2.next = new ListNode(100);
        l2.next.next = new ListNode(300);
        l2.next.next.next = new ListNode(800);

        System.out.print("\nList l1 ");
        l1.printLinkedList();

        System.out.print("\nList l2 ");
        l2.printLinkedList();

        ListNode output = mergeTwoLists(l1,l2);
        
        System.out.print("\nOutput ");
        output.printLinkedList();

    }
}
```

It runs correctly. But my question is that if I replace these 2 lines

```
ListNode currentEnd = new ListNode(0); //the current end node
output.next = currentEnd; // link head to the current end node
```

by `ListNode currentEnd = output;` and change the line `return output.next.next;` to be `return output.next;`it stills gives the correct answer, which I don't understand, because I don't see where the head of the `output` is linked to the `currentEnd`? Could you please let me know why? Thank you.

Comment: Run your code again, the results shoudn't be the same. When you use `ListNode currentEnd = output;`, then the first element will be skipped because you're doing `output.next.next`. The result should be `60, 80, 100, 150, 250, 300, 800` (missing `10` at the beginning)

Comment: Ah yes, I should also change the line return `output.next.next;` to be `return output.next;`, then it will give the same output. However, I was wondering about why `currentEnd ` is linked to `output` in the second case. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `ListNode currentEnd = output;` then your code does this:

```
output = new ListNode(0);
currentEnd = output;
// now both variables point to the same object
```

The first iteration of the while loop:

```
currentEnd.next = ...
```

This is effectively the same as `output.next = ...`, because you said `output = currentEnd`.

But at the end of the loop you change `currentEnd`:

```
currentEnd = currentEnd.next
```

This is effectively the same as `currentEnd = output.next`. But now you assigned a new value to `currentEnd`. This means that from now on `output` and `currentEnd` aren't the same anymore. `output` is still the same as before, because you didn't assign a new value to output. You only changed what `currentEnd` is pointing to.

---

Same same, but from another perspective:

Keep in mind that your variables* `output` and `currentEnd` are basically just pointers. Those variables do not store any data, they just store the memory location of your data. Your code works like this:

`new ListNode(0)` will create a new object in memory. Then you assign the memory location of that object to `output` (using `output =`). Next you assign the very same memory location to `currentEnd` (using `currentEnd = output`).

Now you still have a single object in memory, but 2 variables pointing to it.

Calling `currentEnd.next =`  will go to the memory location of `currentEnd` (which is the same as for `output` in the first iteration of the loop), and then set within this memory location the `next` field.

At the end of the loop you do `currentEnd = currentEnd.next`. This will get the memory location of `currentEnd.next` and then says that `currentEnd` should point to this memory location. This does not change where `output` is pointing to. (If you want to change where `output` is pointing to, there's only one way: You must use `output = ...`.)

I highly recommend that you take a sheet of paper and draw what happens in which order. Then things should become much clearer.

(*) this is only true for Objects in Java, but not for primitive types. But your code only uses Objects, though it's not important here.

Comment: Thank you. I was misunderstood as I thought that `currentEnd` is a different variable that has the same value (a node) as 'ouput`.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit tricky. In fact it's true that Java **did** copy the content of `output` to `currentEnd`, **but** the content of `output` is just the memory location of your `ListNode`. That's how variables for Objects work in Java. If you want to copy an object's data in Java, there's always a `new` involved. But as I said: This is only true for objects, not for primitives (like `int` and `boolean`). When using a primitive Java does store the value in the variable, there's no separate memory location for the data involved. Though when you assign a primitive it will in fact copy the value.

Comment: If you want to learn more about it, here are some search terms for a search engine of your choice: java primitive value object reference

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }*/
 

class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode temp_node = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode current_node = temp_node ;

        while(l1 != null && l2 != null){
            if(l1.val <= l2.val){
                current_node.next=l1;
                l1=l1.next;
            }
            else{
                current_node.next=l2;
                l2=l2.next;
            }
            current_node = current_node.next;
        }
        if(l1 == null){
            current_node.next = l2; 
        }
        else if(l2 == null){
            current_node.next = l1;
        }
    //    current_node.next = l1!=null ? l1:l2;
       return temp_node.next;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).